# Why is the map $(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \mapsto (x-a_1)\cdots (x-a_n)$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Here is a portion of my notes:

> If we impose the norm $\|b\|_\infty := \sup_{x\in [a,b]} |b(x)|$ for $b \in \mathbb C[x]$ then it is clear that the map $\Phi: (\mathbb{C}^n , \| \cdot \|_\infty)  \rightarrow (\mathbb{C}[x],\| \cdot \|_\infty)$ given by $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \mapsto (x-a_1)\cdots (x-a_n)$ is continuous.

Now I don’t understand why this is continuous, I feel like I’m missing something simple.

Comment: Did you try to prove it?

Comment: $n=1$ is a snap. You might try induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $\Phi$ takes value in a finite dimensional complex normed space. Namely the complex polynomials of degree less or equal to $n$. The partial maps defined by

$$a_i \mapsto (x-a_1) \dots (x-a_i) \dots (x-a_n)$$ are affine and therefore continuous. And a (finite) multivariate map whose partial maps are affine is continuous.

Comment: Are you sure it works this way ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Indeed, I need to revisit the answer.